# parameters in visual basic 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, parameters

how can use parameters in my vb application?

i want to make it so that when the parameter its "/y" i want some thing like this to hapen

```
if parameter = "/y" then 
    msgbox("you used the parameter /y")
else
    msgbox("you dint use any parameter")
end if
```

i want some thing like this to hapen when i use the parameter "/y"
the parameters are used when for ex: im running the .exe on cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change Sub Main() to

```
Sub Main(ByVal cmdArgs() As String)
```

And use the argument array that way. This has been valid in VB.NET for many versions.

Comment: how can i say what its a paramenter and whats not?

Answer (score 0):

The passed in command line arguments will be available to the [`Main` procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235406.aspx) of your application.

These come in as an array of strings.

Comment: which exemple i can use that can do what i want?

Comment: @user1341926 - Any of the ones that have a `ByVal cmdArgs() As String` parameter to the `Main` procedure. It is a string array that you can `ForEach` on.

Comment: @user1341926 - The examples in the link I posted have enough detail (and comments).

Comment: @user1341926 - I don't know what that means. The words, in my answer, "`Main` procedure" are [a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235406.aspx). Did you click it?

Comment: yes i clicked it, i made a module whit the code of the last one and when i execute it on the cmd it just opens the form and i get no msgbox

Comment: @user1341926 - You need to have it in the `Main` procedure that your application starts with. You _also_ need to pass in parameters on the command line for it to work.

Comment: and were its the main prodecedure?

Comment: @user1341926 - Look at the project properties. It is normally on `program.vb`